# Kendo UI Bar chart series name from remote data

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, bar-chart, kendo-chart

Hi I am displaying a bar  chart using ASP.NET MVC  4 and Kendo ui Jquery , The chart is displayed correctly and everything works fine but i want to get  the name of the chart series that I've put inside the red circle in the screen shot   from data from the server how can I do  that currently I am using just tstaic strings inside the chart configuration.[image]

```
 seriesColors: ["#f0c300", "#484b42"],
        series: [{
            name: "Oddo Avenir Euro CI-EUR",
            field:"PerfSP",
            categoryField: "date",
            border: {
                width: 0
            }
        }, {
            name: "Indicateur de référence *",
            field:"PerfBench",
            categoryField: "date",
            border: {
                width: 0
            }
        }],
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doc can help you
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/grouped-data

Pay attention to the data in a response

```
[
   {
    "date": "12/30/2011",
    "close": 405,
    "volume": 6414369,
    "open": 403.51,
    "high": 406.28,
    "low": 403.49,
    "symbol": "2. AAPL"
   },
  ...
  {
    "date": "7/29/2011",
    "close": 222.52,
    "volume": 5166268,
    "open": 221.29,
    "high": 225.75,
    "low": 219.51,
    "symbol": "3. AMZN"
   }
  ...
]
```

And config value

```
group: {
      field: "symbol"
      }
```